# Magento 2 - How to change phone form type

Tags: magento2, customer, forms

In Magento 2, I want to change input telephone type to number only in all forms.

I succeed this change in checkout page by following this post :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Change-telephone-input-field-to-number/td-p/93660

But I don't know how to make the same on customer account create and edit forms.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use template path hints to find which `.phtml` file render elements. [This](https://magefan.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2) link should help You to turn this on.
Using this method i found that telephone input on accout edit page is in
`\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\telephone.phtml`.
So You have to override this file in your custom theme or in Your custom module.